# Custom "breakpoint" parameters, not applying. [Reactjs + Material UI]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to implement my custom breakpoints over Material UI breakpoints, however the changes is not applying at all, could some one suggest, where I've made a mistake

**Theme parameters:**

```
export default createMuiTheme({
     palette: {
         common: {
             whiteSmoke: `${ Whitesmoke }`,    
             whiteColor: `${ Whitecolor }`
         },
         primary:    { main: `${ Whitesmoke }` },
         secondary:  { main: `${ Whitecolor }` },
     },
     breakpoints: {
         values: {
             test: 740,
         },
     },
});
```

**Here is the App file, where I'm declaring a break points**

*1 - Imports*

```
import {useTheme}    from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

*2 - Declaration*

```
const Themes  = useTheme();
const adaptbr = useMediaQuery(Themes.breakpoints.down('test'));
```

Comment: you need to put your theme in the theme provider component otherwise it will just resolve the MUI defaults when using useTheme. Here is an example in their [docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#custom-variables). The theme provider just sets an internal context that is used throughout MUI to get the theme.

Comment: @Jacob Smith - Do you mean that I must wrap all my components into Theme Provider?

Comment: My whole app is wrapped into ThemeWrapper on the highest level

Comment: In v4, Material-UI doesn't fully support custom breakpoint keys. There was a change to the documentation 3 months ago (https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/20901) that makes it sound like they are supported more fully than they really are. This has been addressed in the alpha for v5 (https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/21759), but you definitely should NOT use the alpha in production.

Comment: Ryan is right, the keys are hard coded in '@material-ui/core/styles/createBreakpoints' so while you can't create new breakpoints, you can edit all the existing ones.